# Enitity Framework Core auto increment doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, auto-increment, fluent

I'm using the ASP.NET Core MVC template from Microsoft. There I found in the Project Explorer (see  [Printscreen: Project Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3fYh.jpg)) under Data --> Migrations the files "00000000000000_CreateIdentitySchemafil.cs" and "ApplicationDbContextModelSnapshot.cs"

I added to the "00000000000000_CreateIdentitySchemafile" file the follow code:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Flights",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),                   
        StartDate = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: true),
        EndDate = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: true),
        UserId = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 450, nullable: false),
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_Flights", x => new { x.Id });
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Flights_AspNetUsers_UserId",
            column: x => x.UserId,
            principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    });
```

And the follow code to the "ApplicationDbContextModelSnapshot" file:

```
modelBuilder.Entity("Flights", b =>
{
    b.Property<int>("Id")
        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

    b.Property<DateTime>("StartDate");

    b.Property<DateTime>("EndDate");

    b.Property<string>("UserId");

    b.HasKey("Id");

    b.ToTable("Flights");
});
```

```
modelBuilder.Entity("Flights", b =>
{
    b.HasOne("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser")
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey("UserId")
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
});
```

I could successfully create the table and also declare the column Id as PK (see
[Printscreen: DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lyu84.jpg))

Unfortunately when I want to insert a record to this table, it's failed because the Id is null.

In the SQL-Server-Object-Explorer I saw the identity properties (seed, increment etc.) are false and 0 (see [Printscreen: ID-Property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iqu2x.jpg)).
I didn't find out how I can fix this. Can sombody help me here please?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the Annotation method to set the Identity column. Based on your code, I have added a Flights Table on my side, the generated code as below:

```
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Flights",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                StartDate = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
                EndDate = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
                UserId = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Flights", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Flights_AspNetUsers_UserId",
                    column: x => x.UserId,
                    principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_Flights_UserId",
            table: "Flights",
            column: "UserId");
    }
```

and

```
        modelBuilder.Entity("EFCore.Models.Flights", b =>
            {
                b.Property<int>("Id")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                    .HasColumnType("int")
                    .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);

                b.Property<DateTime>("EndDate")
                    .HasColumnType("datetime2");

                b.Property<DateTime>("StartDate")
                    .HasColumnType("datetime2");

                b.Property<string>("UserId")
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(450)");

                b.HasKey("Id");

                b.HasIndex("UserId");

                b.ToTable("Flightss");
            });
```

The result like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately it doesn't work. As workaround I set this properties (seed, increment etc.) manually the sql management studio.